# How to find models depending on fields in associated models

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp

I'm using cakephp_2_3_6. 
I have three models: User, Group and City.

Group has many User.
City has many User.
User belongs to Group and City.

> group => array(
> id, 
> groupName
> )
>
> city => array(
> id, 
> cityName, zipCode
> )
>
> user=> array(
> id, 
> userName, 
> group_id, 
> city_id
> )

I want to offer a search function to people that can find users depending on the groupName of the group those users are in or depending on the cityName those users live in.

```
    public function search(){  
        $url = $this->params['url'];  
        $where = $url['where'];  
        $group = $url['group'];  
        if(!$where && !$group){
            $this->set('foundItems', $this->User->find('all'));
        }elseif(!$group && $where){         
            $this->set('foundItems', $this->User->find('all', array('conditions' => array('User.cityName' => $where))));
        }elseif($group && !$where){         
            $this->set('foundItems', $this->User->find('all', array('conditions' => array('User.groupName' => $group))));
        }else{          
            $this->set('foundItems', $this->User->find('all', array('conditions' => array('User.groupName' => $group), 'conditions' => array('User.cityName' => $where))));
        }
```

As you can see in the code above I used URL to transmit the cityName and groupName from a form.
I tried different things with this code like using  `city.conditions` instead of conditions or use `City.cityName` instead of `cityName` or `User.cityName`. 
According to the CookBook [JoinTable section](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables) "belongsTo" perform automatic joins. So I guess it should be working in some way.

So as I tried many different ways, read a lot on this page and in the CakePHP CookBook and haven't found a solution you might can help me get this search function running?

Here is the user model

```
    <?php
        class User extends AppModel{
        public $useDbConfig = 'sites';
        public $belongsTo = array(  'City' => array(
                        'className' => 'City',
                        'foreignKey' => 'city_id'),
                    'Group' => array(
                        'className' => 'Group',
                        'foreignKey' => 'group_id')
            );

        public $validate = array(
            'userName' => array(
        'rule' => 'notEmpty'
             )
        );

        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. 
The key to what I wanted to do was ContainableBehavior under [deeper associations](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html#containing-deeper-associations) is described how it is done. 
In my example I have to change the find statement like this:

```
    //attach the behavior on the fly, this has to be done once and only with the main Model
    $this->User->Behaviors->load('Containable');
    ....
    $this->User->find('all', array('contain' => array('City' => array('conditions' => array('City.cityName' => $where)), 'Group')));
```

This way I look for a user model that contains City and Group. Now I look only for users that are in the City that Name matches the value of the variable $where.

**Edid**
The solution is not perfect as this way you will always get all users, if they are assigned to a City that matches the condition the City is also returned. And in the above example all Groups are returned too.
**What I accutaly wanted was:**
Only the users that are in the city that matches the conditions and group of this users.
**How I got what I wanted:**
I then looked on and found the solution using [join tables](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables). Using a inner join will return only the users that are in the city that matches the condition.
*Code if you only have conditions for one table*

```
    $this->User->City->recursive = -1;
    ....
    $options['joins'] = array(
            array('table' => 'cities',
            'alias' => 'City',
            'type' => 'inner',
            'conditions' => array(
                'User.city_id = City.id',
            )
            )
        );
        $options['conditions'] = array(
            'City.cityName' => $where
        );
        $result = $this->User->find('all', $options);
```

*Code if you have conditions for two table*

```
    $this->User->City->recursive = -1;
    $this->User->Group->recursive = -1;
    ....
    $options['joins'] = array(
            array('table' => 'cities',
            'alias' => 'City',
            'type' => 'inner',
            'conditions' => array(
                'User.city_id = City.id',
            )
            ),
           array('table' => 'groups',
            'alias' => 'Group',
            'type' => 'inner',
            'conditions' => array(
                'User.group_id = group.id',
            )
            )
        );
        $options['conditions'] = array( 
                'City.cityName' => $where,
            'Group.groupName' => $group
        );
        $result = $this->User->find('all', $options);
```

Comment: what is `Player` model?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake Player is User.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you have groupName in all three tables. Are you sure you posted the right DB structure?

But maybe what you are trying to do is:

```
public function search(){  
    $url = $this->params['url'];  
    $where = $url['where'];  
    $group = $url['group'];  
    if(!$where && !$group){
        $this->set('foundItems', $this->User->find('all'));
    }elseif(!$group && $where){         
        $this->set('foundItems', $this->User->find('all', array('conditions' => array('City.cityName' => $where))));
    }elseif($group && !$where){         
        $this->set('foundItems', $this->User->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Group.groupName' => $group))));
    }else{          
        $this->set('foundItems', $this->User->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Group.groupName' => $group, 'City.cityName' => $where))));
    }
```

(please mind that I just modified the `conditions` options, I didn't cheched if your logic works)

Comment: Thanks for replying. You were right about groupName, this was a copy paste error in my Question. About your suggestion I tried that already as I have seen some hints in CookBook and in some Q&A forums. but it didn't work. Error is: `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'City.cityName' in 'where clause'` Do you have any Idea what could be wrong?

Comment: do you have such a column? You wrote so, but are you sure?

Comment: Yes I do. I think the problem lies somewhere in the find Method, it doesn't generate a sql statement that is correct, the statement is: `SQL Query: SELECT `User`.`id`, `User`.`userName`, `User`.`city_id` , `User`.`group_id` FROM `mycoonline`.`users` AS `User` WHERE `City`.`cityName` = 'Winterthur' ` in this way it tries to find the column in User table instead of the city table

Comment: did you set the relationships correctly? Can you post your User Model file?

Comment: I added it in the question section.

Comment: It's strange: with your relationships cake should create the joins without the need of the containable behavior. Maybe try to set recursive to 1